# Feed a sharepoint list from a google sheet

Tags: import, datasheet, spreadsheet

I have a Google sheet that's being fed from a Google form. I am looking to import the new data into a list on Sharepoint as people continue to submit new items through the form. So far, I've been copying and pasting the new items into the list, but am looking to stop having to do this.
Also, I do not know VBA or the google API language, so a no-code solution would be awesome.

Comment: save the content in csv format, and use powershell to upload the content to a SharePoint List.

Comment: Thank you, but that still means I need to manually do something to update the sharepoint list. The point of this is to stop having to manually update the sharepoint list.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to establish a permanent connection between the two, but you could probably reproduce the functionality of the Google form in a SharePoint form and direct your users to the SharePoint form instead. If this isn't a viable approach, please add some more details to your question. Why do you have both a Google sheet and a SharePoint list?